# How to change/update value in store in redux in react -native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

i am using redux to store the user data like his name,user id ,user image and user email in redux.
The reducer for that is

```
const initialState = {
  user: []
};
function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {

  if (action.type === 'ADD_USER') {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      user: state.user.concat(action.payload)
    });

  }
  if (action.type === 'REMOVE_USER') {
    //return Object.assign({}, initialState)
    return {
      ...state,
      user : []
    }

  }
  if (action.type === 'CHANGE_USER') {

     state.user.splice(0)

    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      user: state.user.concat(action.payload)
    });

  }


  return state;
};
export default rootReducer;
```

To add user i am dispatching like this

```
 let user_id = response[0][1]
          let user_name = response[1][1]
          let user_image = response[2][1]
          let email = response[3][1]

            this.props.add({ user_id, user_name, user_image, email });
```

Suppose now that i want to change the email or name of the user so how can i change/update the specific field like email ? 
Currently i am doing like this

```
this.props.change({ user_id : 1, user_name : 'sdfd', user_image:'', email:'abc@gmail.com' });
```

This passes an action `CHNAGE_USER`
After above line i am calling

```
let a = JSON.stringify(this.props.user)
  console.log("val-----------",a)
```

I mean after updating data i am trying to get latest but it gives me empty array

```
val----------- []
```

Please tell me both the way to change whole object and to change specific field like email ?
Thanks is advance !

Comment: user should be an object not a array

Comment: can u please tell me answer in context of array ?

Comment: like the difference between array [ ] and object { }?

Comment: How can i change if user is an object ?

Comment: @VipinDubey I think you want to have multiple users in store. Am I right? It is array of users or just single user in state?

Comment: There can be multiple users

Answer (score 1):

!!! this is an example for storing data of ONLY ONE USER in redux 
and this don't work if you have many users to store !!!

```
    const initialState = {
        user: {  }
    };
    function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "ADD_USER":
                return {
                    ...state,
                    user: action.payload
                };
            case "REMOVE_USER":
                return {
                    ...state,
                    user: {}
                };

            case "UPDATE_USER":
                /* so you return a new state object with all the data from old state
                user also contain the data from old state.user but you update some of his parameters
                like this.props.updateUser({  email:'abc@gmail.com' }); update only email field 
                this.props.updateUser({   user_name : 'sdfd' , email:'abc@gmail.com' }); update only user_name field

                change the name of action too, because later you will add more item in the redux and "change" dont say it change what ( just an idea )
                */
                return {
                    ...state,
                    user: {
                    ...state.user,
                    ...action.payload
                    }
                };

            default: return state;
        }
    }
    export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: What if there are multiple users ? and if we want to change the email of specific users?

Comment: i write in first of the post that is only for one user. OP write user in singular too. 
for multiple users i will use `users : { }` , and adding new users with `users[action.payload.user_id] = { user_name : action.payload.user_name , user_image:action.payload.user_image, email: action.payload.email } ` . it's faster to remove / edit a specif user with the user_id key, no need to loop over an array

Comment: Hello @Alainlb can u provide me code for update value in multiple users

Comment: As can be seen in the [docs](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns), this is the right way to do it. Thank you @AlainIb.

Answer (score 1):

In the redux documentation you can find recipes for [inserting/removing/updateing](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays) item in an state array.