# How to update a object value in list of array in store in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

The application need to store the list of user details in an array. User details could be: name, email, image etc. I am using redux to store the user detail data.
Here is a reducer for that

```
const initialState = {
  user: []
};
function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {

  if (action.type === 'ADD_USER') {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      user: state.user.concat(action.payload)
    });

  }
  if (action.type === 'REMOVE_USER') {
    //return Object.assign({}, initialState)
    return {
      ...state,
      user : []
    }

  }
  if (action.type === 'CHANGE_USER') {


  }


  return state;
};
export default rootReducer;
```

To add user I'm dispatching like this

```
 let user_id = response[0][1]
          let user_name = response[1][1]
          let user_image = response[2][1]
          let email = response[3][1]

            this.props.add({ user_id, user_name, user_image, email });
```

Suppose now that I want to change the email or name of the user so how can I change/update the specific field like email? Currently I'm doing this

```
this.props.change({ user_id : 1, user_name : 'sdfd', user_image:'', email:'abc@gmail.com' });
```

This passes an action

```
CHNAGE_USER
```

But I don't have an idea how could I change only specific key data in the list of user. Say I want to change user email of user id 3 in list of users in redux store?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change/update value in store in redux in react -native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319905/how-to-change-update-value-in-store-in-redux-in-react-native)

Comment: Hi Vipin, just wrote you an answer, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` to create an updated list of users, where within the `.map()` logic, identify the id of the user who matches your action payload, then update their info. Try something like this:

```
  if (action.type === 'CHANGE_USER') {
     return {
         user: state.user.map((user) => {
            if(user.user_id === action.payload.user_id){
               return {
                  ...user,
                  ...action.payload
               }
            } else {
               return user
            }
         })
     }
  }
```

Comment: This works fine but after this action  this.props.change({ user_id : 1, user_name : 'sdfd', user_image:'', email:'abc@gmail.com' }); when i try to fetch new value then it give previous value , i mean its updating state after some time

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as

```
if (action.type === 'CHANGE_USER') {
  const updatedUsers = state.user.filter(user => user.user_id !== action.user_id)
  return updatedUsers;
 }
```

Hope it helps